# I am creating a next.js app and when i was deploying the app i was getting the below mentioned error. I have all keys unique still facing this

Tags: next.js, deployment, runtime-error, key, vercel

I am creating a next.js app and when i was deploying the app i was getting the below mentioned error. I have all keys unique still facing this.

48:11  Error: Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
48:23  Error: Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
48:34  Error: Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key

heres what the error actually look like.
Below is the peice of code of my file where I am getting error:

```
<div className="flex gap-x-4 xl:gap-x-8 mx-auto xl:mx-0 mb-4">
        {aboutData.map((item, itemIndex) => (
          <div
            key={item.title + itemIndex} // Combined item title and itemIndex for a unique key
            className={`${index === itemIndex && 'text-accent after:w-[100%] after:bg-accent after:transition-all after:duration-300'} cursor-pointer capitalize xl:text-lg relative after:w-8 after:h-[2px] after:bg-white after:absolute after:bottom-1 after:left-0`}
            onClick={() => setIndex(itemIndex)}>
            {item.title}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="py-2 xl:py-6 flex flex-col gap-Y-2 xl:gap-Y-4 items-center xl:items-start">
        {aboutData[index].info.map((item, infoIndex) => (
          <div 
            key={item.title + infoIndex} // Combined item title and infoIndex for a unique key
            className="flex-1 flex flex-col md:flex-row max-w-max gap-x-2 items-center text-white/60"
          >
            <div className="font-light">{item.title}</div>
            <div className="hidden md:flex">-</div>
            <div>{item.stage}</div>
            <div className="flex gap-x-4">
              {item.icons?.map((icon, iconIndex) => (
                <div className="text-xl" key={item.title + infoIndex + iconIndex}> {/* Combined keys for uniqueness */}
                  {icon}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

The data I am using is in this format inside the file:
const aboutData = [

```
{
    title: 'skills',
    info: [
      {
        title: 'Frontend Development',
        icons: [
          <FaHtml5 />,<FaCss3 />,<FaJs />,<FaReact />,<SiNextdotjs />,
        ],
      },
      {
        title: 'Backend Development',
        icons: [<FaJava/>, <FaPython/>,<SiMongodb/>,<SiSqlite/>,<SiMysql/>],
      },
      {
        title: 'Design',
        icons: [<FaFigma />, <SiAdobexd />, <SiAdobephotoshop />, <SiAdobeillustrator />, <SiAdobeindesign />, <SiAdobepremierepro />],
      },
      {
        title: 'Developer Tools',
        icons: [<FaLinux/>, <FaGit/>,<FaGithub/>,<SiVisualstudiocode/>,<SiMicrosoftexcel/>,<SiMicrosoftoffice/>,<SiGoogleslides/>,<SiGooglesheets/>,<SiGoogledocs/>],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

As per my knowledge, I am using the key as unique elements and I am not using any post request as well. I am not able to fix this error please help me out with this.

Have tried using uuid lib for unique ids as well but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the component you are showing is the one throwing the error?